# Configurable Fields that can be showed on visualforce page

Tags: apex, visualforce, custom-object, map, merge-field

[image]

I got this configurable fields from `Event__c`. The configurable fields would be the basis on what fields that will be available on Event Booker Information its object is the `Event_Booking__c`.

[image]

My problem is how to merge this on an inputfield:

Instead of this:

```
<apex:inputField value="{!pbook.First_Name__c}" styleClass="form-control"/>
```

How can I create like this:

```
<apex:inputField value="{!pbook.address__c}" styleClass="form-control"/>

<apex:inputField value="{!pbook.country__c}" styleClass="form-control"/>
```

This is my controller code:

```
String comparelist;
Set<String> comp_set;

events = [SELECT Id,Booker_Custom_Fields__c FROM Event__c
Where Id = :eventId AND Event__c.Booker_Custom_Fields__c != ''
LIMIT 1];

 if(events.size()>0){  

    for(Event__c view: events){
         comparelist = view.Booker_Custom_Fields__c;   
    }
    list<String> comp = comparelist.split(';');
    comp_set = new Set<String>(comp);

    for(String field: comp_set){

        system.Debug(field);                        
    }   
 }
```

field outputs the `address__c` and `country__c`

I initialized this `public Event_Booking__c pbook{get;set;}`

Is there a way how can do this using map? and also the repeat in vf page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I would suggest, probably the easiest and quickest way to do this, is to add all the fields that you want to display on the page, into a field set. Then you can easily reference that field set in your VF page and display each of the fields by using your `pbook` object instance:

```
<apex:repeat value="{!$ObjectType.Event__c.FieldSets.yourFieldSet}" var="fieldName">
    <apex:inputField value="{!pbook[fieldName]}" required="{!fieldName.Required}" />
</apex:repeat>
```

If you want this to be dynamic and you already have the API names of the fields stored in a field, you can put the field names in a Set and itearate through the set. Actually, you already have the set, just add the get/set methods to it:

```
Set <String> comp_set {get; set;}
```

Then same principle in the VF page:

```
<apex:repeat value="{!comp_set}" var="fieldName">
    <apex:inputField value="{!pbook[fieldName]}" />
</apex:repeat>
```

Comment: required="{!fieldName.Required}" means the field is required right? Our scenario is this, each event have different booker info fields based on what the admin drag and drop to showed fields. Which means that Address__c and Country__c will be added on Booker Information on that particular event. I got your point sir but this is the function they want to add.

Comment: Updated the answer

Comment: hi sir if you mind why I got this error 
Save error: Unknown property 'EventsController.comp_set'...

Comment: oh thanks I figured it out. I forgot the 'public'.                                                  public Set<String> comp_set {get;set;}